# How to verify access of child contracts?

Tags: nonce, contract-verification, factory, access

I am using a factory A to produce child contracts. Now I want to guarantee that only these child contracts have access to a different contract B.

Using the factory as a proxy is somehow a detour as I also would like to send stuff back from B to the children. I thought using the nonce of the factory A would be great but this is not accessible in Solidity. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: How about just whitelisting the right contract addresses so only those addresses are able to call the contract B?

Comment: `B` can just ask `A` if the calling contract is a valid caller. (`A` needs to keep a `mapping` of its children.)

Comment: @smarx Thanks! I was thinking to complicated here.